# Problem creating Google Drive shortcuts with specified drive ids (500 error)

Tags: google-drive-api

Does anyone have any experience with creating Google Drive shortcuts with predefined IDs.
After calling `files.generateIds` to get some new IDs, then making a call to create a new shortcut with the pre-generated ids, I get a 400 Bad Request error.

Thank you!

Calls to `files.create` [https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create]

this works - any file with specified ID

```json
{
  "id": "1RHnAOr-lGNBGWJIWZZcT6ogetFosGTuc",
  "name": "testcreatefile2"
}
```

this also works - a shortcut being created

```json
{
  "name": "testcreatefile2",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut"
}
```

does not work - 400 error - a shortcut with a specified id

```json
{
  "id": "1RHnAOr-lGNBGWJIWZZcT6ogetFosGTuc",
  "name": "testcreatefile2",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut"
}
```

UPDATE: with shortcut destination ID set

```json
{
 "id": "<New ID from files.generateIds>",
 "name": "testcreatefile2",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut",
 "shortcutDetails": {
   "targetId": "<existing gdrive document id>"
 }
}
```

returns 500 error from Google:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal Error",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Internal Error",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "internalError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue:

The error you have encountered was due to your wrong request in using `files.create` method, the file Id must be supplied to the `targetId` fields instead of `id` for you to create a shortcut.

You can see the full request and a sample code for creating a shortcut [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/shortcuts#create-shortcut).

### Sample request:

```
{
  "name": "{File name}",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut",
  "shortcutDetails": {
    "targetId": "{File ID}"
  }
}
```

### References:

[Method: files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22shortcut_file%22%2C%22mimeType%22%3A%22application%2Fvnd.google-apps.shortcut%22%2C%22shortcutDetails%22%3A%7B%22targetId%22%3A%221bSI6Xaa6_dVUaGqJZPsDD0_i6_k-2G3BVBOwgQIbo6s%22%7D%7D%7D)

[Create a shortcut](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/shortcuts#create-shortcut)

Comment: Please feel free to ask anything related to the answer posted above.

Comment: Hi George, Thanks for your solution, it partly solves the issue:

```
{
  "id": "<new ID from files.generateIds>",
  "name": "testcreatefile2",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut",
  "shortcutDetails": {
    "targetId": "<existing file id>"
  }
}```


returns a 500 Internal Error from Google APIs

Comment: Try adding the `type=shortcuts` in your [query parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/generateIds?apix_params=%7B%22space%22%3A%22drive%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22shortcuts%22%7D#query-parameters) when using the `file.generateIds` method. It works on my end when I added that parameter

Comment: That was the missing piece! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome Wilson, I am glad I was of help!